# Chi-squared test with more than two variables, or should I run a different test?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, biostatistics, contingency-tables, ecology

I am looking at whether certain animals or categories of animals are more likely to use human-made trails than natural trails. We used camera traps and recorded for every case which animal it was, whether it was on an open or closed trail, and to which category this animal belonged. Here's an example of what the dataset looks like:

```
 open.closed         species.category      ID
  Open               Bird                  Black-Bellied Korhaan
  Open               Bird                  Guineafowl
  Open               Carnivore             Side-Striped Jackal
  Open               Herbivore             Elephant
  Closed             Bird                  Black-Bellied Korhaan
  Closed             Herbivore             Impala
```

So there are three variables with multiple levels: open.closed with two levels ; species.category with five levels ; ID with 48 levels. My logic was that I am testing group differences between more than two groups, and since the data is nominal it cannot be tested for normality, so a chi-squared test seems most fitting to me, but if anyone has a better suggestion I'd be happy to hear it!

Then comes the following issue: when I do a chi-squared using the base R function `chisq.test` I can only enter two variables. Is there any way to test the whole dataset in one test, or would I have to split the dataset and run several separate tests?

Comment: For multiway contingency tables either try loglinear models or glms. There's several independence models that may be considered. There's full mutual independence (additive main effects in a loglinear model), joint independence & conditional independence. You seemed to be asking about the first, but a "split and test" strategy would be testing for one of the others. Agresti's book Categorical Data Analysis has a chapter on loglinear models in three-way contingency tables, if you can borrow a copy. In R there's `loglin` built-in; MASS has a nice wrapper for it (`loglm`), and there's also `glm`.

Comment: In addition to @Glen_b comment, it might be a good idea to take into account the fact that the "species.category" variable seems to be perfectly determined by the "ID" variable (e.g. an elephant is always an herbivore). This might be something to take into account when using a model suggested in the other comment. Also, is there a reason why "bird" is a possible value along "carnivore" and "herbivore" (given that a bird can be herbivore, carnivore, or omnivore)? Isn't this column actually a mix of two variables (e.g. "bird: yes/no" and "feeding strategy: herbivore/carnivore/omnivore")?

Comment: I don't think that any of the suggested independence models would be appropriate though it's an issue with the data collected not with the models. Here is what I think is the issue: You might have multiple sightings of the same animal while the models assume that the observations are independent.